# I am having issues implementing css on create react app

Tags: css, jsx, create-react-app

While building my react app I encountered a problem, basically I am using css modules to style the app, and I am trying to change the display to grid, but it isn't changing, when I inspect,the display I add is overridden by another display "user agent stylesheet" please how could I solve that.

I am using chrome browser

Comment: could you provide some code for that? most of the time it is not need to use `!important` cause it is a bad practice

Answer (score 0):

try adding !important

```
display: grid!important
```

Comment: You have no clue as to whether he can use that cause he supplied no markup and using `!important` is almost always a horrible suggestion. It's a hack at best.